# Send data by post and receive data by post

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have input where i am writing ID and click to button to check if i have such ID(by function). Data goes to 2-nd page by jquery and running function to check, i can even print it to screen. I need to send data from function in 2-nd page to my main page and use this data. How can I send it from 2-nd page without submit?

My First Page:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#checkfin").click(function() {
    var fin = $("#pinofsv").val();

    $.post("checkfin.php", {
      ffin: fin
    }, function(result) {
      $('#result').append(result);
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form name="formids" id="formids" action="" method="POST">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label>Enter your ID: <span style="color:#FF0000;">*</span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="pinofsv" id="pinofsv" required />
                  <div class="input-group-addon"><a href="#" onmouseover="document.getElementById('place-holder-1').src='../svphoto.jpg';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('place-holder-1').src='';"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign blue"></i><img src="" id="place-holder-1" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute;right: 1%;" /></a></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-5">
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary" name="checkfin" id="checkfin" onclick="return false">Check </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-7">

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<div id="result"></div>
```

---

My 2-nd page:

```html
if(isset($_POST["ffin"]) && $_POST["ffin"] != "")
{
  $fintrue = definePINNew($fin);
  if($fintrue != "")
 {
    //do something for example print to screen data from function
  }
  
 }
```

Comment: Is your request going ?

Comment: whenever you send the request you get the response and you can do whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: @OwaisAslam i can do whenever i want in 2-nd page, but i need to do it in 1-st page. just get data from function in my 1-st page

Comment: When you send the request to the second page,  you want some result from the second page's function to return to the first page right?

Comment: @OwaisAslam yes, i am getting post data in 2-nd page as $_POST['name'] and can do whatever i want. I want to get data from 2-nd page(from function) in my 1-st page and do whatever i want)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you send the request you get the response

```
if(isset($_POST["ffin"]) && $_POST["ffin"] != "")
{
  $fintrue = definePINNew($fin);
 if($fintrue != "")
   {
   echo 'JUST SEND YOUR DATA IT WILL BE THERE IN JQUERY RESPONSE';

  Eg: echo json_encode($fintrue['anydata']); 
  // it will give you $_POST data in jquery response.
  // which is at your first page.
  // And parse data in JSON can easily get in jquery response


   }
 }

$(function() {
 $("#checkfin").click(function() {
   var fin = $("#pinofsv").val();
  $.post("checkfin.php", {
   ffin: fin
   }, function(result) {
   console.log(result.anydata); // you will get the data from second page here.
  // result.anydata you can place it anywhere.
  });
 });
});
```

Comment: that jquery function  $(function() {  $("#checkfin").click(function() {... i use it in 1-st page to send data to second page onclick. In backend page(2-nd page) that are no click or submit button. But your upper code, it will just print data in 1-st page from 2-nd page, but still I will be not able use printed data.

Comment: when you send data using ajax call you always can get the response/data from the requested file or page I have just printed it in jquery but you can use it as you want. share your data eg: variable which you want to send from the second page to the first page and share where you want to use it eg: on which element. are you getting my point?

Comment: Yes İ got it, thank you) I want to ask last thing, lets say i am getting data from my 2-nd page function `$fintrue['anydata']`, what should i write to get it and name it to any variable in 1-st page?

Comment: `$fintrue["Name"]` I have this data, and i changed code same as u wrote `console.log(result.Name);` and console shows  _underfined_

Comment: first `console.log(result)` it and see what you are getting and show me as well then we can see the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169141/discussion-between-owais-aslam-and-orik00).

Comment: `console.log(result)` if i do this, it shows me all what i have inside of `if($fintrue != "")
   {
shows in console.log(result) everything what i type here
}`